# AWS Lambda and API Gateway - goes idle; needs to "wake up"/no response on first request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've been tinkering with nodejs code in AWS Lambda, called by some API Gateway endpoints. I've noticed that after a certain amount of time passes without any API Gateway calls, the next API Gateway request will time out. I'll get the standard Lambda error message saying the function timed out. However, subsequent HTTP requests to trigger my Lambda work fine.

Superficially, it looks like something is going into "idle" mode and needs to be charged up before the API Gateway-Lambda request can work properly. I've considered setting up a wget cron to keep things non-idle, but is there a real fix and how can I better understand what's happening?

Comment: Which/whose timeout is firing and how long is the timeout?  (Yes, the resources that continue purring in the background waiting for the next invocation of your Lambda function do indeed get deallocated within about 10 to 15 minutes of no activity, but you should only see increased response time as a result of this, if you don't have something keeping them alive.)

Comment: I have noticed this as well. After being inactive, the next call will take approx 12 seconds to finish. Otherwise I get between 100 and 900 ms

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lambda keeps a worker active for a period of time and will (as you have noticed) remove that worker after a period of time of inactivity. The following is a copy of a set of suggestions posted on [our forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=226070):

> A few suggestions:
>
> 1. Keep your Lambda function "warm". If it's invoked infrequently you will incur an overhead "cold start" cost as Lambda needs to allocate
>      resources to serve your request. See this post for more details.
> 2. Invoke your Lambda function with resource-based permissions as opposed to role-based. This is to avoid the overhead of API Gateway
>      needing to make an assumeRole() request to STS. Resource-based
>      invocation is default if you set it up in the console.
> 3. If appropriate, consider turning on caching for your API.
> 4. Is your API doing any transformations of the request or response via mapping templates? This will obviously incur overhead linear with
>      the complexity of the transformation.

A note, #1 should really only be used as a **last resort** assuming none of the other options work for you.