# Does an AWS state machine (step function) awaken all lambdas on invocation of the first lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I know lambdas go into [an inactive state after 14 days](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36269213/369707) of non-use (AWS docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/functions-states.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/snapstart-activate.html#snapstart-function-states:%7E:text=Inactive%20%E2%80%93%20The%20function%20version%20hasn%27t%20been%20invoked%20for%2014%20days.)), then on invocation, the lambda fails with:

> Resources for the function are being restored. (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 502, Request ID: bd8cd989-2197-4126-a0aa-ad705ed1a9a1)

It then provisions resources (usually taking 2-3 minutes) and makes the lambda active again for calling.

**I've experienced this as well with step functions that are invoked only occasionally with the first lambda that is invoked so failing as above.**

But it ***appears*** that later lambdas in the step function do ***not*** fail due to inactivity. Is there documentation on AWS that confirms that upon the invocation of the "first" lambda in a step function, that the state machine also "awakens" and resources all the other lambdas of the step function (without explicitly invoking them)?

I am assuming this is why later lambdas (that are not used otherwise except in the step function) do not fail, but I would like to know if there is clearer documentation that this is the case. **I have not been able to find such documentation.**

Comment: The behaviour you mention is specific to SnapStart. A normal Lambda environment will disappear after a much shorter period of non-use. The time taken to instantiate a Lambda function depends on the programming language being used -- for example, Java takes longer than Python. You might enjoy reading this series of articles: [Operating Lambda: Performance optimization – Part 1 | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for that input, that is enlightening.